# Subst command not working in CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: windows, cmake

**Subst** command is used to shorten the file path length.

Assume a folder path is as follows: *C:\large_folder_path\large_subfolder_path\large_file_name*

The following command in Windows command prompt will create a new 'Z' drive with all the contents in **large_subfolder_path** directory

```
Subst z: C:\large_folder_path\large_subfolder_path\
```

When I try to use the same command in a CMakeListst.txt file, it doesn't work. Here is the command that I have used

```
execute_process(COMMAND C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe Subst z: C:/large_folder_path/large_subfolder_path/)
```

When I change the above command as below then it's creating a folder with the name "large_subfolder_path_1" under C:\large_folder_path\

```
execute_process(COMMAND C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe Subst z: C:/large_folder_path/large_subfolder_path_1/)
```

I am not sure why **Subst** is not working in a CMake file. FYI. I have tried the **mkdir** command and it works as expected.

Comment: Don't you need `cmd /C some_command ...` to make it run the specified command?

Comment: Thanks for the response @arrowd.
I have tried mkdir command without using /C option and it worked. I am assuming the command that works on Windows should work fine with Cmake as well.

Comment: By the way, if I use /C then the CMake shows this error message "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: FYI. I have also tried to print the current directory but it shows the following error message:

Command used in cmake: execute_process(COMMAND C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe echo %CD%)

Error messages
[cmake] A subdirectory or file .exe already exists.

[cmake] Error occurred while processing: .exe.

[cmake] A subdirectory or file echo already exists.

[cmake] Error occurred while processing: echo.
[cmake] A subdirectory or file C:\large_folder_path\large_subfolder_path\ already
 exists.
[cmake] Error occurred while processing: C:\large_folder_path\large_subfolder_path\